# Google Photos - drag photos between pages in photobook?

Tags: google-photos

Is there any method to drag a photo from one page in a photobook to another?

I have 140 pages of photos and would like to make some adjustments to how the photos are combined.

[image]

If I manually use the "edit collage" button and try to find the photo that way, it could take me 5+ hours (provided I could even sustain the brain capacity to work on it for that long).

[image]

There must be a better solution?

The photobook UX really is awful.